# Android use support library to support SearchView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-search

This is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchMenuItem);
    SearchManager searchManager =
        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    // searchView.set
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
}
```

My minimum API is 8.
I have this compile error

```
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8):
    android.widget.SearchView#setSearchableInfo
```

Note, that I can't change the minimum SDK.

Comment: This error can actually be ignored.  There's a setting in Eclipse to turn it off.  Or if you're in any other file in Eclipse when you hit the debug button it won't stop the build.

Comment: use a editText instead of searchview. what is the min sdk in manifest?

Comment: what do you mean  by cant change minimum sdk?

Comment: @VishalSantharam i mean that I want to support devices 2.2 and later

Comment: @GabeSechan so if i ignored that error, my app still work on android 2.2 and later?

Comment: @Raghunandan can u give me an example please?

Comment: Then you must use android support library.http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: @user2059935 you can use search view from the support library with `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` using `AppCompat` Look @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: Yes.  It would only throw an exception if it actually tried to execute that function, which shouldn't happen due to the if statement.  I've used this pattern in the past and it worked fine.  Although as someone else suggested using the support library may be an even better solution to give your 2.2 users more functionality.  IMO though 2.2 really isn't worth the time to support-  less than 2% of all apps downloaded on Play last month were downloaded with a 2.2 device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use 
*android.support.v7.widget.SearchView*

instead of 
*android.widget.SearchView*

Your code could look like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchMenuItem);
                SearchManager searchManager =
                        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

                searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
                searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

            }
```

Also please read more about **SearchViewCompat**

Comment: I am testing ur solution