# Can i use search view for API level 8

Tags: android, searchview

I was trying to use search View in my application but it showed an error i.e View require API level 11(current minimum is 8).
Is there any method through which i can use this search view by keeping min API level to 8 only?

If there then provide a small code snippet.
Thanks

Comment: yes,  its called a support library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html), the `SearchView` is added in API level 11. If you want to use it below that, use the Support Library: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822721/android-use-support-library-to-support-searchview).

Answer (score 0):

The entire searchview code is available [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/)  with Minimum Required SDK : API 8 : Android 2.2 ( Froyo )

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) of **API 11** and include it in your project in order to use it's components.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sherlock action bar lib.for do this task please refer this link..
[How to implement search widget in Action Bar Sherlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690525/how-to-implement-search-widget-in-action-bar-sherlock)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [v7 appcompat library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) for a backwards compatible `SearchView`. You should prefer this library over action bar sherlock, as the former is Google's own implementation and I believe action bar sherlock is no longer being actively maintained.